# Django: Apache DocumentRoot does not exist

Tags: django, apache, document-root

I'm trying to run Django 1.3.1 on apache 2.6.6, using mod_wsgi, CentOS 6.

I have change httpd.conf file:

```
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/vhosts/domain.co.uk
<VirtualHost *:80>
  #ServerName domain.co.uk
  ServerName 46...233

  ##DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/domain.co.uk/httpdocs

  LogLevel debug
  ErrorLog /var/www/vhosts/domain.co.uk/logs/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/vhosts/domain.co.uk/logs/access.log combinedio

  HostnameLookups Off

  UseCanonicalName On

  WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/vhosts/domain.co.uk/sites/somod/apache/django.wsgi
  WSGIDaemonProcess somod:80 user=somod group=psaserv processes=1 threads=1
  WSGIProcessGroup somod:80
  #WSGIPythonPath /var/www/vhosts/domain.co.uk

  Alias /robots.txt /var/www/vhosts/domain.co.uk/sites/templates/robots.txt
  Alias /favicon.ico /var/www/vhosts/domain.co.uk/sites/media/favicon.ico

  <Directory "/var/www/vhosts/domain.co.uk/httpdocs">
    AllowOverride None
    Options -ExecCGI -Includes -FollowSymLinks -Indexes
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/x-javascript
  </Directory>

  <Directory "/var/www/vhosts/domain.co.uk/sites">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -Includes +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/x-javascript
  </Directory>

  Alias /media "/var/www/vhosts/domain.co.uk/media"
  <Location "/media/">
    SetHandler None
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

So I paste my apache config (only code which I add). This is in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`.

I can restart apache now without any errors, but website isn't visible yet. Unfortunately I couldn't run `sudo a2enmod wsgi`, I'm using cenos 6 and `a2enmod` isn't available. But I'm sure it has been install, because I order vps with it, just not sure it's running. I will check it.

My question now is what url should be to view website? Is it value form ServerName, or `ip address/ServerName value`? Can I use ip address in? Because I want run website and make sure everything is ok before I switch domain, because right now under this domain is website which I'm moving to new server.

Many thanks for help

Comment: What are you doing with `DocumentRoot`? mod_wsgi doesn't use it, and you shouldn't be putting your code there.

Comment: Im using this because it was in config file from privies server. But even if i remove it, apache doesnt start. Im getting `[root@575283 /]# /etc/init.d/httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [FAILED]
Starting httpd:                                            [FAILED]
`.

Comment: You can find more information in `/var/log/apache2/error.log.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know what you're doing, but here's a sample config for you brother:

```
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/yoursite
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName yoursite.com
    ServerAlias testing.yoursite.com

    Alias /static/ /var/www/yoursite/yourdjangoproject/static/
    # Alias /sitemap.xml /var/www/yoursite/yourdjangoproject/static/sitemap.xml
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/yoursite/yourdjangoproject/wsgi.py

    <Directory />
        AllowOverride None
        Options -Indexes
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/yoursite/.git/>
        Deny From All 
    </Directory>

    LogLevel info
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/yoursite-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/yoursite-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Create this file and name it `yoursite` and put it under `/etc/apache2/sites-available`. Then run `sudo a2ensite yoursite` and it will be palced un `sites-enabled`, too.

This depends on:

- `apache2`
- `libapache2-mod-wsgi`

Make sure wsgi is enabled by running `sudo a2enmod wsgi`.

I recommend having the file in your version control repo, and then symlinking it from `/etc/apache2/sites-available`.

Also note that I've created an alias for /static/ and if you want to use that, make sure you run `sudo ./manage.py collectstatic`. This will place all static files in `/var/www/yoursite/yourproject/static`.

Good luck.

Comment: Delete 'DocumentRoot /var/www/yoursite/' and your site will be more secure.

Comment: WSGIPythonPath is sufficient? Could you elaborate on the security aspects?

Comment: Comment out WSGIScriptAlias and all your source code, including passwords in settings.py is available for download. By setting DocumentRoot to be where your site code is with the permissions structure you have for Apache means a simple stuff up in configuration could expose you. It is therefore never recommended to set DocumentRoot to be where your code is located.